# Query That Returns First Results from Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query that returns the results from a subquery in the result set.

Here are the tables I'm using:

```
Orders       OrderDetails     
-------      -----------     
orderId      orderDetailId         
(other data) orderId
             productName
```

I'd like to get the first two order details for each order (Most orders have only one or two details). Here's an example of the desired result set:

```
orderId   (other order data)   productName1   productName2
-------   ------------------   ------------   ------------
1         (other order data)   apple          grape
2         (other order data)   orange         banana
3         (other order data)   apple          orange
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT o.orderid, 
       Max(CASE WHEN detail = 1 THEN oi.productname END) AS ProductName1, 
       Max(CASE WHEN detail = 2 THEN oi.productname END) AS ProductName2 
FROM orders AS o 
    OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 2 oi.*, 
                     Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY orderdetailid) AS detail 
                FROM orderdetails AS oi 
                WHERE oi.orderid = o.orderid) AS oi 
GROUP BY o.orderid
```

I'm doing this in the custom reporting module of a hosted ecommerce solution and getting the following unhelpful syntax error: SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Unfortunately I don't know what version of SQL Server I'm using. Customer support knows nothing and select @@Version doesn't work.

Note, it appears the row_number() function is not properly supported even though error messages reference the function by name.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that does not use cross apply. Your ranking was correct but I added a partition by the order.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        o.orderid,
        ProductName=oi.productcode, 
        RowNumber=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.orderid ORDER BY oi.orderdetailid) 
    FROM
        orders as o
        INNER JOIN orderdetailid oi ON oi.orderid=o.orderid
)AS X
WHERE
    RowNumber=1
```

without using row_number

```
SELECT
    orderdetails.*
    Q1.* 
FROM
(   
    SELECT 
        o.*, 
        FirstOrderDetailID=(SELECT MIN(orderdetails.orderdetailsid) FROM orderdetails WHERE orderid=o.orderid)
    FROM
        orders o    
)AS Q1     
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderdetails oi ON oi.orderdetailsid=Q1.FirstOrderDetailID
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I fixed a little typo to inner join the table orderdetails rather than orderdetailid. After that it gave me the syntax error: SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near 'orderid'. Just for grins, I removed 'Partition by o.orderid' and it gave me the syntax error: SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near '('. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the database you are querying is < SQL SERVER 2005. The documentation for the Row_Number() function only goes back to Sql Server 2005 :( However, that could be due to only showing documentation for supported versions. I verified the query above runs fine on SQL 2008|2012

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but when I remove the Order By from the row_number() function I get this: The ranking function "ROW_NUMBER" must have an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: hmmm...no idea friend.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that, but I really appreciate the insight. Any idea how to do this without using the row_number() function?

Comment: I added a portion above using a query to get min orderdetail and then query again to join it with single a single order. Could be the reporting module is doing something bad.

Comment: I think you may be right that the reporting module is messing things up. Although row_number() appears to be supported, it looks impossible to have it ever accept it syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just selecting `orderid` and the product, you don't need the join at all:

```
select orderid, productcode
from (SELECT oi.orderid, oi.productcode,
             row_number() over (partition by oi.orderid order by oi.orderdetailid) as seqnum
      FROM orderdetails oi
     ) oi
where seqnum = 1;
```

This may not fix the problem if `row_number()` is not working, but it simplifies the query.  You can do this with the `min()` method as well:

```
select orderid, productcode
from orderdetails oi
where oi.orderdetailid in (select min(orderdetailid) from orderdetails group by orderid);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that I need other data from the Orders table. I edited the question to reflect this. I also added the desire to get two order details, rather than just one.